# WorkManger doWork - what methods can I and can't I call from doWork?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-workmanager

As I understand doWork() can run jobs even after the application has ended. Does this mean that I cannot or should not call member methods such as members of my Repository class ?

Or in other words, how should I safely update my Room database after the application has ended, or even when the application exists from doWork().

Answer (score 0):

RxJava is created to handle such kind of situations only. Create a separate rxJava callback and on success of the API call just update your database. In my case i created a separate class for API call and onSuccess of the API i just update my database.

> Worker just hit the API and returns the success call, so you should not call any other async call which is dependent on the earlier API call, instead you handle it on response of the API, better to use RxJava with Retrofit/OkHttp/Volley. One worker is supposed to do one task. If you don't understand this architecture i will help you by codes.